# Can't update bullet rigidbodies position connected to Ogre3D entity

Tags: c++, ogre, bulletphysics, ogre3d, bullet

I am making a game using Ogre3D and Kinect.
The avatar in Ogre is controlled by the kinect. Now I want to implement physics but I am running into problems with Bullet.

I have "connected" the entities with the rigibodies with pairs.

```cpp
std::vector<std::pair<Ogre::Entity *, btRigidBody *>> dynamicObjects;
std::vector<std::pair<Ogre::Entity *, btRigidBody *>> staticObjects;
```

I have no problem getting my Ogre enities follow the rigidbodies like this:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < dynamicObjects.size(); i++) {
try {
    btTransform tr;
    dynamicObjects[i].second->getMotionState()->getWorldTransform(tr);
    btVector3 pos = tr.getOrigin();
    btQuaternion qut = tr.getRotation();
    dynamicObjects[i].first->getParentSceneNode()->setOrientation(Ogre::Quaternion(qut.getW(), qut.getX(), qut.getY(), qut.getZ()));
    Ogre::Vector3 localPos = dynamicObjects[i].first->getParentSceneNode()->getParentSceneNode()->convertWorldToLocalPosition(Ogre::Vector3(pos.x(), pos.y(), pos.z()));
    dynamicObjects[i].first->getParentSceneNode()->setPosition(localPos);
} catch (Ogre::Exception e) {
}
```

However I can't seem to do the opposite, by making the rigidbodies follow the entity, which is necessary for the player controllet by Kinect. This code does not seem to do anything.

```cpp
btTransform tr;
staticObjects[0].second->getMotionState()->getWorldTransform(tr);
Ogre::Vector3 entityPos = staticObjects[0].first->getParentSceneNode()->getPosition();
tr.setOrigin(btVector3(entityPos.x, entityPos.y, entityPos.z));
staticObjects[0].second->setWorldTransform(tr);
```

Both parts are placed in an update loop.

Comment: Does `entityPos` has the correct value, according to your debugging process?

Comment: You really should debug the values. I suspect that you should pass `getParentSceneNode()->getDerivedPosition()` to physics, as it seems that you use world frame there and local frame on scene node